# How to set timer to show text after certain period of time on screen in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uikit

In my app I have a black screen at one point and I want the user to know that it's not the end. I want to display text "tap to go next" on the bottom of the screen. To do that I'll need to use timer to show the text after couple of seconds. I don't know how to do it. Could anyone show how should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

[`scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:repeats:block:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer) will allow you to execute functionality after a specified time.

Your code should look something like this, where `label` holds the text you wish to show:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { _ in
    label.isHidden = false
}
```

One other option would be using a `DispatchQueue`. You could use [`asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300020-asyncafter) like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    label.isHidden = false
}
```